# how to get a field from database in the form build in infyom (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment

I have a field in the form that is to be fetched from the database.
But there is no such option given in INFYOM laravel form generator for such database transactions. 
I have tried the relational table options but not working. So is there any other option that can help me fetching data in the input field created in infyom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Laravel Generator** package supported to generate CRUD from existing database.

its docs here: https://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/5.8/generator-options#generate-from-table

**command**:

`php artisan infyom:scaffold $MODEL_NAME --fromTable --tableName=$TABLE_NAME`

also supported for specific connection (database).

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan infyom:scaffold model --fromTable --tableName=model_table
```

for API you can use this

```
php artisan infyom:api model --fromTable --tableName=model_table
```

or this one

```
php artisan infyom:api_scaffold model --fromTable --tableName=model_table
```